# FactoryGirl build ignored when testing with Shoulda Matchers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I've recently switched over to Shoulda Matchers, but can't seem to validate my factory builds. I've instantiated my factory build in a before callback, but the matcher doesn't seem to even acknowledge it. For instance, I intentionally set my instance's name to `nil` but the test returns no errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Restaurant do
  context 'validations' do
    before { FactoryGirl.build(:restaurant, name: nil) }

    it do
      should validate_presence_of(:name)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario, you don't require an instance to match with Shoulda matchers; it's only going to test [the *usage* of `validate_presence_of`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveModel%3Avalidate_presence_of) against the model definition itself.

So, I'd rewrite your test as thus:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Restaurant do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

Comment: So from what I understand in a sense it's just checking whether that particular model has the `presence` validator associated with the `:name` attribute?

Comment: Pretty much.  I'm willing to bet that there actually *is* some checking of the attribute with test data within the matcher, but that instance isn't something that you have to provide or exercise.

Comment: I see. How then would you test factories with shoulda-matchers?

Comment: In my experience, it's never made sense to test a *factory* directly; if I'm testing something about the model itself that requires an instance of it, I do so in a manner that I see fit.  But I feel like that may be its own question. ;)

Comment: If you want to test a factory, you could build it and test that it's valid, or use FactoryGirl.lint.

Comment: @ElliotWinkler:  Please no; if you have more to add about this, you should start your own question and answer on it.  This question isn't about testing factories.